# Doubly Periodic Entire Functions

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-functions, entire-functions

> Theorem : Every entire function $f$ so that $$f(z)=f(z+1)=f(z+i) $$ on $\Bbb{C}$ is necessarily constant

Proof:

Consider the solid square $S:=\{x+iy : 0\leq x,y \leq 1\}$.

Since $f$ is continuous on $S$, there exists an $M$ so that $\vert f(z) \vert \leq M$ on $S$.

Now, let $z \in \Bbb{C}$ be arbitrary.

$\textbf{Clearly, we can find two integers $m$ and $n$ so that $z+m+in$ in S }$  and therefore,

$\vert f(z+m+in) \vert \leq M$ for $z \in \Bbb{C}$. Further, the hypothesis imply that $$f(z)=f(z \pm 1)=...=f(z+m+in)$$ showing that $f$ is bounded on $\Bbb{C}$ as the behaviour of $f(z)$ over $\Bbb{C}$ is completely characterized by its behaviour on the compact set $S$.  Hence $f$ is constant by Liouville's theorem.

I cannot understand the boldface line. If the chosen $z$ is from $S$, then $m=n=0$ is easy. What about other $z's$?

Can anyone explain this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $z=x+iy$ for real numbers $x,y$. Now let $x=m.a_{1}a_{2}\cdots$, the decimal expression, then $x-m=0.a_{1}a_{2}\cdots\in[0,1]$.

Comment: So if $z=x+iy$ where $x=m.a_1a_2....$ and $y=n.b_1b_2.....$ then $x+iy+(-m)+i(-n)=(x-m)+i(y-n) \in S$ where $-m \in \Bbb{Z}$ and $-n \in \Bbb{Z}$. Am I right?

Comment: Thank you so much!